# jakarta mail with TLS and checkserver identity problem

Tags: java, ssl, smtp, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send an email with jakarta mail, with tls and checkserveridentity but it fails with an exception:

`jakarta.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS; nested exception is: java.io.IOException: Can't verify identity of server: XXXXXXXXXXX.com at org.eclipse.angus.mail@2.0.2/org.eclipse.angus.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:2173)`

when i dig deeper it happens in the org.eclipse.angus.mail.util.SocketFetcher class:

`java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class org.eclipse.angus.mail.util.SocketFetcher (in module org.eclipse.angus.mail) cannot access class sun.security.util.HostnameChecker (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export sun.security.util to module org.eclipse.angus.mail`

I tried with Java jdk 11 and 17
I'm using jakarta.mail-api-2.1.2, jakarta.activation-api-2.1.2, angus-mail-2.0.2, angus-activation-2.0.1

I found a bug report which seems similar but doesnt help:
[text](https://github.com/jakartaee/mail-api/issues/391)

My code is:

```
        String to = "some1@mail.com";
        String from = "some1@mail.com";
        String host = "mail.host.com";
        final String username = "some1@mail.com";
        final String password = "somePWD";
 

        Properties properties = System.getProperties();
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.ssl.checkserveridentity", "true");
        properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        properties.setProperty("mail.debug", "true");
        
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties, new Authenticator() {
             
            protected PasswordAuthentication
                    getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
            }
        });
     

        try {
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
             
            // header field of the header.
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
             
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                                  new InternetAddress(to));
            message.setSubject("subject");
            message.setText("Test mail");
            // Send message
            Transport.send(message, username, password);
        }
        catch (MessagingException mex) {
            mex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Without checkserveridentity it just works fine (properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.ssl.checkserveridentity", "false").

The host uses a let's enrcypt certificate which is in my default truststore, so this shouldn't be the problem.

Does anyone have any suggestion, workarounds, bugfixes, new versions?

Answer (score 0):

You found the correct link which has the correct workaround of using --add-opens but you have to look at the module name in your exception to see that the correct open was added. What happened is that JakartaMail split the API from the implementation after that comment was written you need to change the module name from `jakarta.mail` to `org.eclipse.angus.mail`

```
--add-opens 'java.base/sun.security.util=org.eclipse.angus.mail'
```

This issue [Angus Mail: Illegal reflective access by com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher #124](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/angus-mail/issues/124) should be fixed in Angus Mail 2.0.3 with some [caveats](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/angus-mail/docs/COMPAT.txt).